# How can I create a LINQ view?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-4.3

My team is using Entity Framework 4.3.0 - Code Only with POCO classes as our ORM.  Right now we use DBSets of Classes to access our 'tables'

```
Public Property Customers As DbSet(Of Customers)
```

But often we are doing soft deletes based on a IsDeleted column in LINQ, and filtering our select statements accordingly:

```
Dim LiveCustomers =
    From C In EM.Customers
    Where C.DeleteFlag = False
```

What I would really like to do is, instead of writing every query to include this filter, create some lower level property (possibly at our inherited DbContext level) that provides the filtered set, while maintaining strong type.

I tried this:

```
Public Property Customers As DbSet(Of Customer)

Public Property Customers_Live As DbSet(Of Customer)
    Get
        Return From C In Customers
                Where C.DeleteFlag = False
    End Get
    Set(value As DbSet(Of Customer))
        Customers = value
    End Set
End Property
```

However that yielded me this error:

**Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'Customers' and 'Customers_Live' can both contain instances of type '*_*_.Customer'.**

A quick check on google yielded this promising result ([How to: Query Objects with Multiple Entity Sets per Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738586.aspx)) But after updating my Connection String, I'm still getting the same error.

```
  <add name="EntityManager"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
       connectionString="
          Data Source=xxxxxx;
          Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;
          User Id=xxxxxx;
          Password=xxxxxx;
          MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
```

So my question is, how could I effectively create a LINQ view that allows me to apply filtering, without impacting the upstream usage too drastically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your property like this:

```
Public Property Customers As DbSet(Of Customer)

Public Property Customers_Live As IQueryable(Of Customer)
    Get
        Return From C In Customers
                Where C.DeleteFlag = False
    End Get
End Property
```

This is slightly different, as you won't have things like `Add()` or `Remove()`, but for a view you typically wouldn't expect to have that kind of functionality.  If you want to add a new one, or remove one you should use the normal `Customers` property.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your POCO classes inherit from a new class that has a new method that would do the filtering for you. Add something like this to the new class
--PSEUDO CODE!--

```
Public Function Filtered() as IEnumerable(Of Out T)
    Return (From x In Me Where x.DeleteFlag).ToList()
End Function
```

and you could call it like:
Dim LiveCustomers = 
    From C In EM.Customers.Filtered

Or you could create an Interface and do a dependancy injection when you call your linq query.  You'll have to google that one :)

Comment: I like the idea, but I don't think it will actually work.  You would need to make a class inheriting from DBSet(Of Customer).  Pretty sure this is not possible.  It creates a design time error about DbSet not having a publicly accessible 'Sub New'